# Defining ORM relationships in sqlalchemy

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm diving head-first into sqlalchemy ORM and am trying to understand relationships between objects.

I've created 3 classes that represent log files (Log), records parsed from the log files (LogRecord) and users (User) that each log record belong to.

Here's how I defined the classes:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import random

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
# Create the session class
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
# Create the session
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()

class Log(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'logs'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    log_name = Column(String, unique=True)
    records = relationship("LogRecord", backref="logs")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Log(log_name={:s}, id={:d}>'.format(
            self.log_name, self.id)

class LogRecord(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'log_records'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    record_name = Column(String)
    log_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('logs.id'))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

    user = relationship("User", backref="log_records")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<LogRecord(record_name={:s}, id={:d}>'.format(
            self.record_name,
            self.id)

class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User(name={:s}, id={:d}>'.format(self.name, self.id)
```

And then populated them with some phony data:

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

users = ['John', 'Alex', 'Nikki']

# Add 10 log files to Log
for x in range(0,10):
    log = Log(log_name='log{:d}.txt'.format(x))
    session.add(log)

# Add users
for user in users:
    session.add(User(name=user))

# Select all users
users = session.query(User).all()

# Add log records
for log in session.query(Log):
    # Assign a random user to each log record
    user = users[int(random.random() * len(users))]
    for x in range(0,10):
        # Assign a random user to each log record
        user = users[int(random.random() * len(users))]
        r = LogRecord(record_name='{:s}-{:d}'.format(log.log_name, int(random.random()*100)),log_id=log.id,user=user)

        session.add(r)
```

Each log file can contain records from one or more users.  I'd like to get a distinct list of log files which contain at least one record from a specified user.  I tried:

```
In [8]: user = session.query(User).filter(User.name == 'John').one()

In [9]: user
Out[9]: <User(name=John, id=1>
```

and then tried to find the logs using:

```
In [10]: session.query(Log).filter(Log.records.user == user).all()
```

But got the following:

```
session.query(Log).filter(Log.records.user == user).distinct().all()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-d6d323e178f8> in <module>()
----> 1 session.query(Log).filter(Log.records.user == user).distinct().all()

/Users/kerfoot/code/venvs/sqlalchemy/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.pyc in __getattr__(self, key)
192                     type(self.comparator).__name__,
193                     self,
--> 194                     key)
195             )
196 

AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Log.records has an attribute 'user'
```

Not sure if there's something wrong with my class defs or the query itself.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make filters on the *properties of the properties*, or simply put: you are not able to have more than one dot in the expression: `Log.records.user` does not work.

**Option-1:** You can do this the same way you would do it in the SQL:

```
session.query(Log).join(LogRecord, Log.records).filter(LogRecord.user == user).all()
```

and `sqlalchemy` is smart enough to return you only the list of `Log` instances without any duplication (even though SQL statement might result in repetition).

**Option-2:** Another way is to use [`any(...)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any), which is *logically* cleaner:

```
session.query(Log).filter(Log.records.any(LogRecord.user == user)).all()
```

> Transcript:
>   -> get all `Log` instances,
>   -> which contains at least one `LogRecord`,
>   -> that belongs to given `user`.